# Display result from SQL using mysqli_fetch_all

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is my code:

```
$sel = $conn->query("SELECT user FROM db_user WHERE level='1'");
$rsel = mysqli_fetch_all($sel, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($rsel);
```

so, it will give the result:

> [{"user":"reg-60"},{"user":"reg-76"}]

How to get the result just name of user?
So in browser just show: reg-60, reg76

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a `foreach` loop and then use `implode`

```
<?php

$sel = $conn->query("SELECT user FROM db_user WHERE level='1'");
$rsel = mysqli_fetch_all($sel, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ($rsel as $result){
  $temp[]= $result["user"];
}

echo implode($temp,",");

?>
```

Note: For your case you are hardcoding the query condition to `level='1'`. But if the condition depends on user provided data (e.g.  $_POST["level"]) then you should amend the select query to **parameterized prepared statement (see below)** which is resilient against SQL injection.

```
<?php

$level='1';
// the above can be a user-supplied data such as $_POST["level"];

$sel = $conn->prepare("SELECT user FROM db_user WHERE level=?");
$sel->bind_param("s",$level);
$sel->execute();

$result = $sel->get_result();
$rsel = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach ($rsel as $result){
  $temp[]= $result["user"];
}

echo implode($temp,",");

?>
```